# Finding X binary numbers with n non-zero digits for large X. - Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

Is there a more efficient method for generating X binary numbers (that have n non-zero digits) for a range of 1 to N? I have developed the following solution:

```
Totalcombos = nchoosek(N,n);                             
floor = floor(log2(Totalcombos));
L = 2.^floor;    
NumElem = 2^N-1;
i=0;
x=1;
%Creates Index combination LUT 
while 1
    %Produces Binary from 1 : NumElem
    binNum= de2bi(x,N,'right-msb')';
    x=x+1;
    %Finds number of bits in each binary number
    NumOfBits = sum(binNum);    
    %Creates a matrix of binary numbers from 1:NumElem with n 1's
    if NumOfBits == n
        i=i+1;
        ISmatrixShapes{i} = binNum(:,:);
    end
    if i==L
        break
    end
end
ISmatrixShape2=cell2mat(ISmatrixShapes);
ISmatrixShape=ISmatrixShape2(:,1:L)';
```

Is there a way to generate these values without a massive number of loop iterations?

Comment: Just a heads up: `floor = floor(..)` is not good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generates all `N`-digit binary numbers that have `n` ones and `N-n` zeros:

```
N = 5;
n = 3;
ind = nchoosek(1:N, n);
S = size(ind,1);
result = zeros(S,N);
result(bsxfun(@plus, (ind-1)*S, (1:S).')) = 1;
```

It works by generating all combinations of `n` positions of ones out of the `N` possible positions (`nchoosek` line), and then filling those values with `1` using linear indexing (`bsxfun` line).

The result in this example is

```
result =
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     0     0     1
     1     0     1     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1
```

---

Another, less efficient approach is to generate all permutations of a vector containing `n` ones and `N-n` zeros, and then removing duplicates:

```
result = unique(perms([ones(1,n) zeros(1,N-n)]), 'rows');
```